# What were the life spans of the four Mars rovers?

Tags: mars

What were the life spans of all 4 rovers that were sent to Mars?  By 4 rovers i mean Sojourner,  Spirit and Opportunity and Curiosity?

Which of them 4 had maximum and minimum lifetime span?

Comment: Welcome, one of the life spans is still growing !

Answer (score 10):

[*Sojourner*](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/mars-pathfinder-sojourner-rover/) was planned to be a seven day mission, but ended up having a life span of 83 days, about 12 times its designed life.

The rover was deployed the evening of July 5, 1997, and its last transmission was received via *Pathfinder* at 10:23 UTC on September 27, 1997.

---

[*Spirit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_(rover)) was planned to be a 90-sol (about 92 days) mission, but ended up having a life span of 2269 days. After 1944 days it ceased to be mobile after it got stuck in soft sand, but it continued to do science as a stationary platform. Whichever way you look at it, it lasted over 20 times its designed life.

*Spirit* landed on Mars at 4:35 UTC (Earth-received time) on January 4, 2004. It got stuck in the sand on May 1, 2009, and then sent its last transmission March 22, 2010.

---

Like its twin *Spirit*, [*Opportunity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)) was planned to be a 90-sol (about 92 days) mission, but ended up having a life span of 5250 days, over 55 times its designed life!

*Opportunity* landed on Mars on January 25, 2004 at 5:05 UTC spacecraft local time. It sent its last transmission June 10, 2018.

---

[*Curiosity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)) was planned to be a two year mission. Its primary mission ended after 668 sols (687 days), but it has continued to operate for a total lifetime of 2597 days so far. It has already survived 3 times its designed life, and since its mission was extended indefinitely it may continue to operate for some time.

*Curiosity* landed on Mars on August 6, 2012 at 5:17 UTC spacecraft local time.

---

**In summary, the top lifespan is currently held by *Opportunity* at 5250 days, and *Sojourner* had the lowest lifespan at 83 days. However, even *Sojourner* exceeded its designed lifespan.**

Comment: Interesting to note that the first rover was designed to last a week, but after it lasted months the next rovers were designed to last months. When they lasted years, the next rover was designed to last years.

Comment: @Uwe Sojourner's operations log doesn't always indicate when driving occurs, so I may not be able to get precise. https://mars.nasa.gov/MPF/ops/rover.html

Comment: @Uwe I count six days where it is explicitly noted that the rover stayed at a certain feature or had no operations that day.

Comment: How can a time be both UTC and local (except at the prime meridian)?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson It's a way of indicating if the time referenced is before or after the speed of light delay in communication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_Event_Time

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98855/discussion-on-answer-by-called2voyage-what-were-the-life-spans-of-the-four-mars).